# How to configure eslint with files to include?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have a react native application that doesn't follow the convention of having all files in `src` directory. It appears eslint looks for the src directory by default.

How can I tell eslint to look for `./components',` ./screens' etc instead?

Passing in the path when running eslint works but that means those files only get checked when that command gets ran instead of allowing my text editor to detect issues.

```
"lint": "eslint ./**/*.tsx"
```

I have tried adding include paths to my eslint config too but that doesn't make any difference.

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    'react-native/react-native': true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'standard-with-typescript',
    'plugin:react-native-a11y/android'
  ],
  overrides: [
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    'react-native'
  ],
  rules: {
    indent: ['error', 2],
    'linebreak-style': [
      'error',
      'unix'
    ],
    semi: [
      'error',
      'always'
    ]
  },
  includePaths: ["./**/*.tsx"] // this doesn't seem to have any effect
};
```

I want to be able to run `eslint` and not have to pass in any optional args as it should be defined already within my eslint config.

Comment: Try to override `files` array inside `overrides`.

Comment: @0stone0 no luck unfortunately. Running `eslint` doesn't run on my required directories